# EF Core 3: CLR property 'Number' cannot be added to entity type 'CHSIMTBase' because it is declared on the CLR type 'Contract'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to create a relationship between two classes **ContractItem** and **Contract** based on a contract number.

This relationship:

1. targets a derived class **Contract**
2. does not use **Contract** 's principal Key named **Reference** but **Number**

When using HasPrincipalKey( c => c.Number) on the relationship **Contract-ContractIem**, an error tells CLR property 'Number' cannot be added to entity type 'CHSIMTBase'.

But **Contract** is a derived class of abstract base class **CHSIMTBase**.

I could not find a way to create the relationship between **Contract** and **ContractItem**.

I tried to move the property Number on CHSIMTBase but

- the CHSIMTBase is not a Contract
- CHSIMTBase is abstract (there is no discriminator for this type )

#### Steps to reproduce

Here is the model and the context to reproduce the error:

```
    public abstract class CHSIMTBase
    {
        public int Reference { get; set; }
        public string ContractKey { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contract : CHSIMTBase
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CustomerContractLink> CustomerContractLinkRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerContractLink : EntityLink
    {
        public int Reference { get; set; }
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }
        // public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContractItem
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }
       // public Service Service { get; set; }
    }

    public class CoherisContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CHSIMTBase>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Reference);
                entity.ToTable("CLIENTS");

                entity
                    .HasDiscriminator(e => e.EntityCode)
                    .HasValue<Customer>( (int) EntityCodes.Customer )
                    .HasValue<Site>(     (int) EntityCodes.Site )
                    .HasValue<Partner>(  (int) EntityCodes.Partner )
                    .HasValue<Contract>( (int) EntityCodes.Contract );

                entity.Property(e => e.Reference)            .HasColumnName("REFERENCE");

            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasBaseType<CHSIMTBase>();

                entity
                    .HasMany( e => e.CustomerContractLinkRef )
                    .WithOne(c => c.Contract )

                // entity
                //     .HasMany(e => e.ContractItems)
                //     .WithOne(i => i.Contract)
                //     .HasPrincipalKey(i => i.ContractKey)
                //     .HasForeignKey(i => i.ContractNumber);
                //     
                entity.Property(e => e.Number)        .HasColumnName("CL_RUB1");
            });


            modelBuilder.Entity<ContractItem>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("AF_LINK");
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Code);
                entity.Property(e => e.Code) .HasColumnName("AF_CODE");
                entity.Property(e => e.ContractNumber) .HasColumnName("AF_INFO_COMP1");

                // generate error CLR property 'Number' cannot be added to entity type 'CHSIMTBase' because it is declared on the CLR type 'Contract'.
                entity.HasOne( e => e.Contract)
                    .WithMany().HasPrincipalKey( c => c.Number).HasForeignKey( e => e.ContractNumber );
            });
        }
    }
```

#### Further technical details

EF Core version: 3.1.6
Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework:  .NET Core 3.0
Operating system: Windows 10
IDE: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I'm wondering if it will complain about the fact that ContractNumber is an int, and Number is a string. That would explain why it's kind of looking for an int equivalent in the base but it doesn't find it, so it tells you it can't create one for you. This is my guess.

Comment: Well seen, I updated the post. But it does not change anything, the same error is thrown.

Comment: It almost seems as though EF can't consider any property that's not in the base class, which I don't see a reason for it. I can't find anything that supports that theory, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF Core 3.1 version does not support using an alternative key as foreign key in a relationship, if that mapped alternative key is part of a derived class ( https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21974 ).

For the entity **Contract**, the principal key is **Reference** and the alternative key used in the relationship with **ContractItem** is **Number**.

So the solution was to move the alternative key's property **Number** from the derived class **Contract** to the base class **CHSIMTBase**.

The downside is that property is accessible to all derived classes. If another propery of a derived class is mapped on the same column, then a common name must be chosen to match both properties (or use derived well-named properties that point to that property shared in the base class).